# How to automatically run the command when running PHP storm "php artisan serve"?

Tags: laravel

please tell me how to automatically run "php artisan serve" and "npm run dev" in PhpStorm when opening?
I arrived to go to "Startup Tasks" -> "pressed "+" -> selected "Add New Configuration", and then what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.